# Proof that the 2-norm of orthogonal transformation of a matrix is invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, invariance

For any matrix A and an orthogonal matrix Q, I can prove in the standard way that 
$$\|QA\|_2 = \|A\|_2 $$
using
$$\|QA\|_2^2 = (QAx)^T(QAx) = (Ax)^T(Ax) = \|A\|_2^2 $$

However, I am unable to cancel Q, when the transformation is AQ, i.e.
$$\|AQ\|_2^2 = (AQx)^T(AQx) = x^TQ^TA^TAQx$$
After this point I am unable to prove the same that $$\|AQ\|_2 = \|A\|_2 $$

Comment: Where does the $x$ come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the 2-norm for matrices is defined as 
$$\|B\|_2 \;\; =\;\; \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Bx\|.$$

But for any orthogonal matrix $Q$ we have that $\|Qx\| = \|x\|$.  Thus in your computation we can write 
$$\|AQ\|_2 \;\; =\;\; \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|AQx\| \;\; =\;\; \sup_{\|Qx\|=1} \|AQx\| \;\; =\;\; \sup_{\|y\|=1} \|Ay\| \;\; =\;\; \|A\|_2.$$

Comment: How do you know that the range of $Q$ is the entire vector space?

Comment: @user42493 $Q$ is orthogonal, hence invertible.